# Using google cloud plateform to analyse logs

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform

What is the best way to store logs in GCP from a external system (ex: embedding system) , and analyse it .

Thanks.

Comment: GCP is an entire family of products, you ned to be more specific. Either specify the GCP product you desire or detail your requirements. You should show that you did your homework - maybe list what solutions you thought about and ask for pros/cons. Otherwise your question is pretty much off-topic for SO and will likely be closed.

Comment: i want to store my logs in GCP plateform from a raspberry device or a android device, in the future that will be a bigdata so i should take that in the consideration, an other thing that i want use this logs to build a machine learning models, and improve the user expérience

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver Logging is the thing you're looking for.  Here's an example of how it's used:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/stackdriver-logging-for-dgs

Comment: can i analyse my logs from this tools, and make prediction models, if is not can i connect this tools with bigquery or machine learning engine,, and is support a big amount of logs (bigdata)

Comment: Yes, you can export StackDriver logs by "sink-ing" them directly to BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2